# Filter ToolBar for a table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, angular7

I have a `user[]` object that gets data from an API.I'm trying to filter the data based on `fullName`(property of the object), on `keyup.enter` it calls a `filterUser()` function.This is where I wrote my filter logic. The data is getting a filter but Angular is not able to render it, I don't know what am I doing wrong.

I'm saving my filtered Data in an object `filterData` of type `User[]`.

> **User-list.html**

```html
<div *ngIf="users?.length > 0">
<div> <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="filterUser($event)"> </div> <!--function triggering here-->
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
{{item.attribute.fullName}}
</div>
</div>
```

> **User-list.component.ts**

```js
// assuming users has some data
items: User[]
filterData: User[];
 filterUser( searchTerm: string) {
    this.filterCount = 0;
    console.log('searchTerm', searchTerm);
    console.log(typeof(this.items));
    if (!this.items || !searchTerm) {
      return this.items;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      if (this.items[i].attributes.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {         this.filterData[i].attributes.fullName = this.items[i].attributes.fullName;
        this.filterCount++;
      }
    }
    this.items = this.filterData;// I'm not able to copy data back to this.items
  }
```

I don't know what am I missing. Do I need to use `ngOnChanges()`?.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it by creating **custom pipe**

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
        searchText=searchText
        if(!items){ return ;}
        if(!searchText){
            return items;
        }
        return items.filter( it => {
            return it['fullName'].toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
        });
    }
}
```

Register the pipe in app.module.ts file

```
import {
  FilterPipe
} from 'PipePath'; //give the path of custom created pipe

declarations: [...,FilterPipe],
```

user-list.html

```
<div *ngIf="users?.length > 0">
<div> <input type="text" (keyup.enter)="filterUser($event)" [(ngModel)]="search"> </div>
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filter : search">
{{item.attribute.fullName}}
</div>
</div>
```

Declare search variable in ts file as we are using ngModel.

user-list.ts

```
search;
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake when you copy matching item into your filteredData list. Here is a possible solution using spread operator copy :

```js
class Test {
    // assuming users has some data
    constructor() {
        this.items = [
            { attributes: { fullName: 'toto1' } },
            { attributes: { fullName: 'toto2' } },
            { attributes: { fullName: 'tutu3' } }
        ];
        this.filterData = [];
    }
    filterUser(searchTerm) {
        this.filterCount = 0;
        console.log('searchTerm', searchTerm);
        console.log(typeof (this.items));
        if (!this.items || !searchTerm) {
            return this.items;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            if (this.items[i].attributes.fullName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                this.filterData[i] = { ...this.items[i] }; // Copy full object using spread operator
                this.filterCount++;
            }
        }
        this.items = this.filterData;// I'm not able to copy data back to this.items
    }
}
let test = new Test();
test.filterUser('toto');
console.log(test.items);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer mate :).But I'm getting an error as `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: strange as the snippet is running well on stackoverflow (you can verify it by clicking the button above). can you edit your post with the code you're running?